# One-to-many in DynamoDB with Java Object Persistence Model

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Is possible to create a relationship between two tables using DynamoDB Java Persistence Model?

I have the follow relationship of One Post to Many Comments

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="Post_MyApp")
public class Post {

private String id;
private String title;
private Set <Comment> comments;
//... Getters and setters and dynamo annotations
}
```

I have a separated table of comments, that Comment is another dynamo table/entity.
My idea is create a table of post_comments like in SQL with all the comments of a post. This is the right way to do this with Dynamo or there is another way to do it better?

Answer (score 4):

One post to many comments. You just need the following tables:
1. Post table: post-id (Hash Key), 
2. Comment table: post-id (Hash Key), comment-id (Range Key)

To get all the comment for a post, you query the comment table by just giving the HashKey (post-id).

On Java side, you will have 2 classes (Post, Comments) mapped with the Dynamo DB Mapper.

DynamoDBMapper (AWS SDK for Java - 1.7.1) : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Java SDK at all but, from a design point of view, may I suggest you a "DynamoDBier" approach ?

#### Table `Post_MyApp`

- article_id as `hash_key`
- title
- ...

#### Table `Comments_MyApp`

- article_id as `hash_key`
- datetime as `range_key`
- text
- ...

This allows you to get all comments for an article in a single `Query` and even to paginate using `limit` and `ExclusiveStartKey`

By the way, I found excellent examples In DynamoDb documentation's appendix: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleTablesAndData.html